# How to add a subscript on a xlab statement?

Tags: r, subscript

I would like to add the following `xlab` and `ylab` to my graph but need to have the `10` after the Log as subscript. See my R statement below. How can I modify it to accomplish that? I know you can use the expression command and also add the number in `[]` but after several trials I did not get it to work as wished.

> title (xlab="Log 10 for total ASF genome copies", ylab="Cycle threshold value", outer=TRUE, line=3, family="serif")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` inside an `expression` to combine math and plain text:

```
plot(1:10,
     xlab = expression(paste(Log[10], " for total ASF genome copies")),
     ylab = "Cycle threshold value")
```

[image]

See also `?plotmath`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is my final coding. title (xlab = expression(paste(Log[10], " for total bacterial genome copies")),
     ylab = "Cycle threshold value", outer=TRUE, line=3, family="serif")